# AngularJS $ filter date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi I am using Angular $filter function to filter the dates in grid. I want to show the dates descending order but every time the empty dates comes upper, how i can show the empty dates lower in grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly

user orderby [orderBy filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

```
{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse}}
```

define your own getter function and instead of null return lowest possible date